# data.table performance not scaling linearly on computing lagged differences of a column by group

Tags: r, performance, data.table

Fairly new to data.table. After two years of resisting, I finally gave in given the size of my data. I am trying to compute 'wait' time by group based on lagged differences of time (POSIXct) as follows:

```
dt <- data.table(id = c(rep('a', 5), rep('b', 5)),
                 time = (Sys.time() + rnorm(10, 100, 10)))
dt <- dt[order(id, time)]
dt[, wait := difftime(time, shift(time, fill = min(time), type = 'lag'),
                      unit = 'mins'),
   by = id]
```

This works fine, but when I run it on 11.5 million rows with nearly 100,000 groups (id), it takes about 10s (of user time and elapsed time) where as the same code on 45 million rows with nearly 200,000 groups (id), it takes 300+ seconds of user time (and more than twice 730 seconds of elapsed time). I am measuring run time with `system.time` command wrapped around the code.

Any thoughts on why such utterly non-linear scaling in performance? And, how I might get it to scale linearly by writing perhaps better data.table code?

Comment: Should rows be sorted by `time` within each `id`?

Comment: @Frank Yeah, I pre-ordered the rows using `dt[order(id, time)]`. Did not include. Will edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort the data by your grouping vars, do the `difftime` on the overall table, and then fix the first row of each group:

```
ng = 1e5
n = 5L
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(
    id = rep(1:ng, n),
    time = (Sys.time() + rnorm(n*ng, 100, 10)))
setorder(dt, id, time)

system.time(
    dt[, wait := difftime(
       time, 
       shift(time, fill = min(time), type = 'lag'),
       unit = 'mins'
), by = id][]
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    8.48    0.00    8.50 

system.time({
    dt[, wt := difftime(time, shift(time, fill=time[1L]), units='mins')][]
    dt[dt[,.I[1L], by=id]$V1, wt := 0][]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.03    0.00    0.04
```

Comparing the results...

```
dt[wait != wt, summary(as.numeric(abs(wait - wt)))]
#      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
# 3.179e-06 4.140e-05 9.469e-05 9.898e-05 1.274e-04 2.514e-04 

dt[, which.min(time), by=id][, table(V1)]
# V1
#     1     2 
# 99958    42
```

The small difference in the results is due to some rounding in `setorder`, but doesn't amount to much, as seen here. If you were using `time` defined at the second, you wouldn't see this at all, I guess. If you really need time vs the min time, you can use `setNumericRounding(0)` before `setorder`.

(As Arun mentioned in a comment, I'm making some assumptions about your data size.)

Comment: Amazing solution and incredibly faster. I will try it later on the 46 million data set as I need to kick it off on AWS, but on the 11 million data set, this takes one second vs. 10 seconds for the previous solution. As for the data, in my data, there are just literally two more numeric columns, which I am not using in this computation. My `id` values are extremely long strings (36 characters). Any thoughts on why performance in original code is so non linear?

Comment: I think that making 200,000 calls to `difftime` instead of one is what slows it down (but there may be more to it than that that I don't realize).